# How to filter the data based on particualr column for the current fiscal year in sql

Tags: sql, dax

> Fiscal Duration is : July to June I have a [Due Date] column in the
>   table. Now i need to filter the remaining columns data based on [Due
>   Date] column which is Current Fiscal Year Data. Here Requirement is i
>   should not do hardcode for getting the date, because if we entered in
>   to next fiscal year, we have to get next fiscal year data
>   automatically.
>
> Please can any one can suggest either the DAX measure or Sql Query for
>   this logic.

Comment: In order to increase chance of good answers, I suggest you to follow the template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Example with some tables,  4) Expected Result related to the example provided at (3)-

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract the year and month from your table by creating a view (ViewStep1) that uses those attributes:

   TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR ((DUE_DATE), 'YYYY')) AS YEAR

   TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR ((DUE_DATE), 'MM')) AS MONTH
2. Then you can use those columns to filter for each fisical year. Or even better, create another view that has a column FISICAL_YEAR which gets it´s data from a subselect of your previous view. Add a simple case in that subselect and your done:

   select YEAR as YEAR, MONTH as MONTH, DUE_DATE,
           (case
               when MONTH >= 7 then YEAR
               else (YEAR - 1) END) as FISICAL_YEAR
   from ViewStep1 order by YEAR desc, MONTH desc, DUE_DATE desc;

If you have issues creating a view then I would advise to look into the documentation of your database system.

Comment: I am not understand the second point clearly. Please can you explain in detailed manner

Comment: By using this i will get highest fiscal year right. In my table future FY also there

Comment: You will get a list of your entries that is ordered by the Fisical year yes.

Comment: Yes, but i need current fiscal year

Comment: Okay, I missunderstood your question. But it works pretty similar: Just apply step 1 to your current time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the fiscal year, just subtract six months.  So the current fiscal year would be something like this:

```
where year(dateadd(month, -6, duedate)) = year(dateadd(month, -6, duedate))
```

You should be able to adapt this idea to your code.